# REGEX How to select from 3 guids, the last?

Tags: regex

I have text:

```
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__#AFEA039__BE75C8DB7825E0C7'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.@Table'. The duplicate key value is (35012149-8f1a-4ccd-adec-ba3058722b23, 6c4039ec-8ee3-4494-a307-75da78a422f4, b5885502-4ca1-4aa1-b8ef-45c9d0548cbb).
The data for table-valued parameter "@Table" doesn't conform to the table type of the parameter. SQL Server error is: 3602, state: 30
The statement has been terminated.\
```

Is it possible to match last Guid b5885502-4ca1-4aa1-b8ef-45c9d0548cbb by regex in one match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may enough for this example at least `(?<=, )[\w-]+(?=\))`.

https://regex101.com/r/ZxkVMJ/3

Also `\S+(?=\))` is sufficient as @JvdV suggested and even shorter.

Comment: Maybe even `\S+(?=\))`